# Python Decorator function

Tags: python

I am tweaking a Telegram bot.

I have several async functions that lead to specific actions. Since I am using handlers and commands to call the bot, in every function I need to split the user message or atleast the first word. I am looking for decorator function that can do this for me instead of me putting another line of code into the main functions.

This is an example function. I am sending message to the bot "/wiki stackoverflow", then I split the "/wiki" part and use the variable "stackoverflow" & wikipedia library to do the thing. I want to split the command with decorator.

```
async def wiki(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    text_input = str(update.message.text.split(' ', 1)[1])
    wiki_text = wikipedia.page(f'{text_input}')
    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, `text=(wiki_text.summary))
```

How can I create a function that I will be able to put as decorator, @decorator for example, and this will split the user message associated with the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just like you make any other decorator

```
def my_decorator(fn):
    def __inner(update:Update, context:ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
        text_input = str(update.message.text.split(' ', 1)[1])
        wiki_text = wikipedia.page(f'{text_input}')
        return fn(wiki_text, context)
    return __inner

@my_decorator
def some_thing(wiki_text:str, context:ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    return context.bot.send_message(...)
```